# Prove lower bound on length of polygon inscribed on $(x, x \cos(\pi / x))$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, arc-length

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Consider the curve
> $$ 
> \begin{align*}
> f(t) &= (t, \cos(\frac{\pi}{t}) \textrm{ whenever } t\neq 0 \\
> f(0) &= (0, 0)
> \end{align*}
> $$
> Let $P$ be the partition
> $$P = \{0, \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n-1}, ...,\frac{1}{2}, 1\}$$
> Show that the inscribed polygon $\pi(P)$ has length:
> $$
> |\pi(P)| \geq 1 + 2(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n})
> $$

I've tried to set up the length a few different ways, but I haven't gotten any expressions that have the form from above.

What I have so far is: let $P_k = \frac{1}{k}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$, and ignore the point at 0 for now. Then the length of the $k$th segment is given by $|| f(P_{k+1}) - f(P_k) ||$. Doing some algebra, and taking  advantage of the fact that $\cos((\pi + 1)k) = -\cos(\pi k)$:

$$
\begin{align*}
f(P_k) &= (\frac{1}{k}, \frac{\cos(\pi k)}{k})\\ 
f(P_{k+1}) - f(Pk) &= (\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k}, \frac{\cos(\pi(k + 1)}{k+1} - \frac{\cos(\pi k)}{k})\\
&= (\frac{-1}{k^2 + k}, \frac{\cos(\pi(k+1))}{k + 1} + \frac{\cos(\pi(k+1))}{k} \\
&= (\frac{-1}{k^2 + k}, \frac{-(2k +1)\cos(\pi k)}{k^2 + k})
\end{align*}
$$

So taking the norm I end up with $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{(k^2 + k)^2} + \Big(\frac{(2k + 1)\cos(\pi k)}{k^2 + k}\Big)^2}$$

and since $\cos(\pi k)$ is always either $1$ or $-1$, it becomes:
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{(k^2 + k)^2} + \Big(\frac{2k + 1}{k^2 + k}\Big)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{(2k+1)^2 + 1}{(k^2+k)^2}}$$

and the first few terms of the sum are $\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$, $\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{\frac{13}{2}},...$, which does not match what I'm expecting, and seems to be a bit numerically smaller.

Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks -- I think that was a transcription error from my notes, the terms of the sum listed match the correct form.